# Merging two methods

Tags: java, string, methods

I have this bit of code that is meant to alphabetize three words. I'm trying to remove the method at the bottom, and simply add it to the code above. However, I can't figure out a working way to do so. Any guidance or help would be appreciated, thank you!

```
    System.out.print("Please enter three words: ");
    final String words = keyboard.nextLine();
    final String[] parts = words.split(" ");

    if (parts[0].equals(parts[1]) && parts[1].equals(parts[2])) {
    System.out.println("All three of those words are the same!");

 } else  {

         System.out.print("In alphabetical order those are: ");
         alphabetizing (parts);
         final int three = 3;
         for (int limit = 0;  limit < three;  limit++) {
         System.out.print(parts[limit] + " ");
         }
  }
  }

  public static void alphabetizing (final String[]  parts) {
        int word;
        boolean check = true;
        String temp;

              for (word = 0;  word < parts.length - 1;  word++) {
                      if (parts[ word ].compareToIgnoreCase(parts[word + 1]) > 0) {
                                  temp = parts[word];
                                  parts[word] = parts[word + 1];
                                  parts[word + 1] = temp;
                                  check = true;

                      }
              }
        }
  }
```

Comment: why would you want to do this?

Comment: You should extract your code into more methods, not the other way around.

Comment: @ScaryWombat It's for an assignment. I was requested to remove the method.

Comment: I agree with what @Tom says.  Google for *a function should do one thing*

Comment: Yes, in real life, this particular function should stay separate. However, there are times when it makes sense to join functions together, and Shibaku's assignment is practice for those times.

Comment: @Shibaku Can you explain what you have tried so far? You say you haven't yet figured out a working way, but can you show a non-working way?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to do it anyway. I don't see any problem why it will not work. Just add it into the else statement where you are calling the method and it should work.

```
    System.out.print("Please enter three words: ");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    final String words = keyboard.nextLine();
    final String[] parts = words.split(" ");

    if (parts[0].equals(parts[1]) && parts[1].equals(parts[2])) {
        System.out.println("All three of those words are the same!");

    } else {

        System.out.print("In alphabetical order those are: ");

        //boolean check = true; you don't neeed this.
        String temp = "";

        for (int word = 0; word < parts.length - 1; word++) {
            if (parts[word].compareToIgnoreCase(parts[word + 1]) > 0) {
                temp = parts[word];
                parts[word] = parts[word + 1];
                parts[word + 1] = temp;

            }
        }
        final int three = 3;
        for (int limit = 0; limit < three; limit++) {
            System.out.print(parts[limit] + " ");
        }

    }
```

Output :

```
Please enter three words: a b c
In alphabetical order those are: a b c 
Please enter three words: a a a
All three of those words are the same!
```